# Unique record among x number of objects in a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unique, has-many

I have the following models

```
class Acceptance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :requested_favor
  belongs_to :offered_favor
end
```

and

```
class RequestedFavor < Favor 
  has_many :acceptances, foreign_key: 'favor_id'
end
```

and

```
class OfferedFavor < Favor
  has_many :acceptances, foreign_key: 'favor_id'
end
```

Multiple users can send `acceptance` request to a particular `favor` object. `acceptance` has a boolean `accepted` attribute.

What I need is when an `acceptance`'s `accepted` is set to `true`, no other `acceptance` object can be set to `true`. Sort of a validation or uniqeness I guess. I did my best to explain the situation clearly :)

How to achieve this? Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic way to approach this would be to check before you save an acceptance and make sure that the "OfferedFavor" instance it belongs to does not already have any other "accepted" acceptances. In your acceptance model, the check would look something like this:

```
offered_favor.acceptances.where(accepted: true).count > 0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Your solution made me think and I came up with `acceptances.any?{ |acceptance| acceptance.accepted }` Now the next question is what should I do if this is true. Should I raise an error or redirect or something else? Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to help! Depending on if you're using AJAX, you might just set up an endpoint that returns a JSON response indicating whether or not the save succeeded, and then update the UI accordingly. But there are lots of ways to approach that problem depending on the UI/UX goals, good luck!